# What is the difference between sys.stdout.encoding, locale.getpreferredencoding(), and sys.getdefaultencoding()?

Tags: python, encoding, locale, sys, codepages

I am new to python and really confused about this encoding stuff. So far, I've read about the following types of "encoding":

```
import sys
import locale

print (sys.stdout.encoding)
print (locale.getpreferredencoding())
print (sys.getdefaultencoding())
```

output:

```
utf8
cp1252
utf-8
```

What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, encoding is way your data is stored inside memory.The different ways, allow for more characters, and information. For an in-depth explanation you are more than welcome to read either http://kunststube.net/encoding/, or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding)

In python you can change the way things are stored by either physically calling an encoding type, or with the use of any of [the coding function](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/codecs.html?highlight=encoding#module-encodings.utf_8_sig).

For your environment of python3.x, there is no difference between `sys.stdout.encoding` and `sys.getdefaultencoding()`. They both use the 8-bite code units (most standard). While the preferred encoding,`locale.getpreferredencoding()` (`cp1252`), is the windows version of `latin1`.

Note that if you would like to get quick feedback with any method/function, you can always use the help command.

Example:

```
>>> import locale
>>> help(locale.getpreferredencoding)
```

Output:

```
Help on function getpreferredencoding in module locale:

getpreferredencoding(do_setlocale=True)
    Return the charset that the user is likely using,
    according to the system configuration.
(END)
```

Comment: "There is no difference between `sys.stdout.encoding` and `sys.getdefaultencoding()`" …in _this particular case_, yes, this is true; but I think it’s also worth noting that this is _not_ an invariant truth that always holds. E.g., if `PYTHONIOENCODING` has been set, then `sys.stdout.encoding` will reflect that, but `sys.getdefaultencoding()` will not.